system's clock is set to the correct time when set variable for mongodb

When Im trying to add my mongodb url with clerk, this error occurs and I dont know what to do with the system's time. I have been set it automatically, the error dissapear when I try delete the mongodb_url in .env file.

Please help me, I have been stucked in this issue for 2 hours.
